# Absolute positioning is a few pixels off

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have an icon within a `div`, positioned vertically using absolute positioning. The `div` is 39px tall, and the icon is 10px tall:

[image: Image with highly apparent labels]

I want this icon vertically centered within the `div`. My inspector (on Chrome) says that the icon is 14.5px away from the top:

[image: Did I really need to screenshot text?]

which would mean the icon should be perfectly, vertically centered within the div. However, it does not look that way. So I measured it. The `div` is indeed 39px tall and the icon is 10px tall, however... my eyeballs were correct about the image not being centered: the space above the icon is 16px, and the space below is 13px:

[image: What the H! Have the correct space already!]

Why is the space above the icon not 14.5px like Chrome says it is and like my code says it will be? Where is the disconnect?

P.S. - I can understand 15px spacing on top and 14px spacing below due to rounding issues, but having a difference of 1.5px gets rid of that theory.

P.P.S - here is an example that more or less reproduces the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/0shzub2t/

P.P.P.S - and here is an example that is a deviation from my code for easier visualization: I think it shows the issue because in the example, I should have the top edge of the image right on the bottom edge of the div but the image is several pixels higher than it should be...
https://jsfiddle.net/0shzub2t/1/

Comment: Could you supply the offending code?

Comment: I just tested this in a plain `<div>` with a single `<img>`. The problem was [*not present*](https://jsfiddle.net/t697d0u4/). Please ensure you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code -- in doing so you'll almost certainly identify the problem.

Comment: The code is spread out all over the place so it will take me a while to get the relevant stuff. Also, your example uses ```margin-top``` instead of ```top``` like mine does. In your example, get rid of ```margin-top``` from your ```.container``` section and change ```margin-top``` to ```top``` in your ```img``` section. That reproduces it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to have links to examples of the error reproduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `position: relative;` to the `.container` element, otherwise the absolute position of the image will not relate to its parent `.container`, but to the next "higher" element which has `position: relative`, or – if there is no such element – to the root element, which is `html`.  And `html` in most browsers has a default `margin` setting, so your centered positioning is off by that margin setting.

But as I wrote: just add `position: relative;` to `.container`